# Constraint in DB table for Sql and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where i should restrict the data to be inserted in table where one column with the same value and other column with null . for ex :

I have the below table, i want to restrict the 3rd row to be inserted where Name column with the value A which exists already and Salary as Null. I want to write a constraint for the same in Database. Can some once pls help

| Id | Name | age | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 30 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 32 | 5000 |
| 3 | A | 30 | NULL |

Comment: should any other combination of name and salary (not null) should be allowed or not ?

Comment: Try adding a composite primary key on name and salary, if you don't want to allow nulls as well. Composite unique key won't work because it will allow duplicate with nulls

Comment: yes @praveen This should be allowed

Comment: did you try unique index function ? (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1249800833250)

Comment: Yes @praveen.. But handling only for Null values is Getting Tricky

Comment: @praveen Unique index will treat a combination of values as null if any key in the composite key is null. that is it will allow duplicate values in A if the salary is null.

Comment: Don't use my answer it will cause a mutating error.

Comment: Using Pragma autonomous_transaction will solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a unique index function like below (works only if id is unique). just a try. there may be better way. see if it helps

```
create unique index t1_idx1 on table1( name || decode(salary,null,-1,id) );
```

fiddle url : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=95489755afa5946e3e78857a057ba742

Comment: It is a good solution but the index will be useless for many scenarios and may decrease performance for large data sets because of the decode function. Optimizer won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER name_check
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON salary
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  cnt PLS_INTEGER;
  duplicate_name EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

  IF INSERTING THEN

    SELECT count(*) into cnt FROM salary WHERE name = :NEW.name AND salary IS NULL ;
    IF cnt >= 1 AND  :NEW.salary IS NULL THEN
      RAISE duplicate_name;
    END IF;

  END IF;

END;
```

You can expand it for update statements as well.

Comment: I missed something now I have updated in the answer